# Question about Artin's 1966 notes

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

I would like to know if the notes of the commutative algebra course that Artin gave in MIT in 1966 are available online, or if there is any book related. I'm following a course that covers some topics of algebraic geometry from that point of view (mainly algebraic), but I can't find them anywhere; thank you in advance.

Comment: They seem to be a hot item ... https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48943/commutative-ring-notes-by-m-artin